# How to scrape Chegg Textbook Solution pages using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Long story short, I was re-visiting exercises in an old VBA textbook to do some practice (specifically *VBA for Modelers - 5th Edition, S. Christian Albright*).

In doing so I wanted to retrieve the answers for the exercises and in doing so I came to Chegg and thought I could try to scrape the code blocks in the solution pages (example hyperlinked below).

[Sample Chegg Textbook Solution Page - code block and HTML in red rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i9At.png)

I've been trying to get more acquainted with python and thought this would be a good project to learn more about web scraping.

Below is the code I began with as I realized that it would not be as simple as scraping the HTML from each solution page. I initially just wanted to find all `div` elements on the page itself before going further and looping through each exercise page, and scraping the code blocks as such.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# scrapeChegg.py - Scrapes all answer code blocks from each problem exercise in each chapter for a textbook (VBA For Modelers - 5th Editiion)

import bs4, os, requests

# Starting URL point
url = 'https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/open-new-workbook-get-vbe-insert-module-enter-following-code-chapter-5-problem-1e-solution-9781285869612-exc'

# Retrieve sol'n HTML
head = {'User Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0'}
res = requests.get(url, headers=head)

try:
    res.status_code
    cheggSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    print(cheggSoup.find_all('div'))

except Exception as exc:
    print('Issue occurred: %s' % (exc))
```

Within one of the `div` results, the output was as follows:

```
<p>
                Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the
                website.
            </p>
<p>
                This may happen as a result of the following:
            </p>
<ul>
<li>
                    Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)
                </li>
<li>
                    Your browser does not support cookies
                </li>
</ul>
<p>
                Please make sure that Javascript and cookies are enabled on your browser and that you are not blocking
                them from loading.
            </p>
<p>
                Reference ID: #5ca2ea20-0052-11ec-8c04-7749576e4445
            </p>
</div>
```

So based on the above, I can see that the page is stopping me from using automation tools. I've looked at similar issues that people have brought up concerning scraping from Chegg, and a lot of solutions are beyond my current knowledge (i.e. various solutions had more key/value pairs within the *head* dict that I was not sure how to interpret).

Essentially **my question is how can I gain more knowledge (or what resources should I look deeper into - i.e. HTTP, scraping with python, etc.) to make this project work**, if possible that is. If anyone has made something like this work before, I would appreciate any advice on what to look at for myself or how I can make this specific project successful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-` in `User Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/open-new-workbook-get-vbe-insert-module-enter-following-code-chapter-5-problem-1e-solution-9781285869612-exc"

# Retrieve sol'n HTML
head = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0",
}

res = requests.get(url, headers=head)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")

print(soup.h1.text)
```

Prints:

```
 VBA for Modelers (5th Edition) Edit editionThis problem has been solved:Solutions for Chapter 5Problem 1E: Open a new workbook, get into the VBE, insert a module, and enter the following code:Sub Variables() Dim nPounds As Integer, dayOfWeek As Integer nPounds = 17.5 dayOfWeek = “Monday” MsgBox nPounds & “ pounds were ordered on ” & dayOfWeekEnd SubThere are two problems here. One causes the program to fail, and the other causes an incorrect result. Explain what they are and then fix them.…
```

Comment: Made use of your edit to *User-Agent* key, and tried with ```res.content``` versus ```res.text```. When printing ```soup.h1.text```, I receive: ```Please verify you are a human```. Is this because I am hitting the page too often? Just curious why we have differing results.

Comment: @mvoight Yes, could be the reason you are getting the page too fast - and your IP gets banned.

Comment: Ah I see ok, looking at the full soup I can see I am seeing the same result I was receiving in my initial question. Is there a way to bypass this any further? Sorry for the lack of knowledge concerning this topic.

Comment: @mvoight If your IP is already banned then there is little to do. You can wait till ban is lifted or use proxy/different IP address.